# Java input check using negative lookahead regex

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to using a regex negative lookahead to check if any invalid characters have been entered.  The characters I want to check for are everything but 0-9, whitespace, *, /, +, -, r, x.

```
String word = "(l4+3q)*(5+7-8)/(5)";
Pattern p  = Pattern.compile("(?![\\d\\srx*+-/)]+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(word);

if(m.matches()) System.out.println("NO");
```

In this current test code, every string I use returns false.

Could anyone provide me with some direction on how to modify this regular expression to work for my specifications.

Comment: how about `"yourString".matches("[^-\\d*/+xr]+")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use this `+-/` in that order in the class.
The `-` used this way is a range operator, not a literal -.
To make it literal, add it to the end or beginning, or escape it
and it can be anywhere.

Basically, you want to match anything *not* in that class.
`Pattern p  = Pattern.compile("[^\\d\\srx*+\\-/)]");`

If it matches `if( m.matches() )` it did find an illegal character.
or,
If it doesn't match `if( !m.matches() )` it didn't find an illegal character.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me.  Using the test if(m.matches()) for your regex and the string "(4+3+qfadfcxbvs)" does not return true.  Have any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @prior - I don't use Java, and I'm not sure if _match()_ needs to match the entire line. Use `".*[^\\d\\srx*+\\-/)].*"`if that's the case. Regarding the regex `[^\d\srx*+\-/)]`, given your string it matches these highlighted characters. `(` 4+3+ `q` `f` `a` `d` `f` `c` x `b` `v` `s` )

Comment: I figured out what was wrong.  I switched back to using the find() method and it worked.  Thanks for your help!